# Is this MustacheJS-Snippen safe against XSS attacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss, mustache

I have a MustacheJS Template with the following image:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style='background-image: url({{avatar}});'></div>
```

The `{{avatar}}` variable is populated from user input without validation, and the user can enter whatever they want.

Is this safe, or can somebody pass some evil input and execute XSS through this?

Comment: No it's not safe. You need to validate and sanitise the input.

Comment: We'd have to see your exact code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please provide an input-value which will lead to JavaScript beeing executed? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Feathercrown What code do you want to see? The avatar-variable is coming from an user input and it is passed to the template you can see above. Thanks!

Comment: `'foo.jpg); /* any javascript code here */'`

Comment: I guess this is all we'd need to see, just checking if you had any sanitization. Since you don't, @Rory McCrossan's example could cause you some problems.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried it out. My input was: `'foo.jpg); /* <script>alert(1);</script> */' ` This is what mustacheJS rendered: `<img src="'foo.jpg); /* &lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt; */' " alt="">` . So no JavaScript was executed.

Comment: Ok - in that case mustache escapes the HTML for you. Still not ideal, but at least it should stop any XSS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How is that not ideal - I don´t see any attack vector. The problem here is, that I can not (!) validate the user-input on the server.

Comment: Because it will still dump rubbish in to the DOM. Ideally you would detect HTML in the input before hand and prevent it even being submit

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just had an idea. I´ll validate on the client-side and if the input does not look good, I´ll ignore it. (Like I said, there is no way of me doing this on the server). This should be best I can do in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think style XSS does not work anymore in modern browsers anyway (either IE11 / Edge, recent Chrome or Firefox won't run JS from CSS).

So it also depends on the browser version, but even if it's not the best practice, it would not be straightforward to come up with an attack that actually works (and I was very cautious with wording there, it's probably not possible to exploit this in recent browsers). Even more so because as you demonstrated in your comment, Mustache html encodes some characters automatically.

Note that IE can be switched to compatibility mode with `X-UA-Compatible`, in which case it behaves exactly like the version selected, with all of that version's vulnerabilities, but because of the html encoding, it's probably still not exploitable.